# how do i insert number series which start with 100 in mysql php?

Tags: mysql

I was trying to insert number in my database which should be start with 100. following is my query which i tried to insert in my database but it is showing every time with one not by 101.

```
INSERT INTO jps_final_tickets(ft_ticket_number, ft_event, ft_package_id, ft_contact_person)
                SELECT COUNT(ft_ticket_number)+1, '$eventID' AS ft_event, '$ticketID' AS ft_package_id, '$contactPerson' AS ft_contact_person,
                FROM jps_final_tickets WHERE ft_package_id = '$ticketID'
```

Above query showing following output, everything is fine but ticket number should be start from 100 series.

```
-------------------------------------------------
| Ticket Number | event ID | Ticket Id | Name    |
|     1         |   645    |   70      | Santosh |
|     2         |   645    |   70      | Sandeep |
|     1         |   645    |   71      | Sahil   |
|     1         |   645    |   72      | Jagveer |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Following output which i want:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| Ticket Number | event ID | Ticket Id | Name    |
|     101       |   645    |   70      | Santosh |
|     102       |   645    |   70      | Sandeep |
|     101       |   645    |   71      | Sahil   |
|     101       |   645    |   72      | Jagveer |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Please help me how can i insert above ticket number in my table.

Comment: you have 100 records already in that table?

Comment: no i do not have 100 records. i gonna to inert first value in my table.

Comment: Then you are usinhg count +1 -- that counts previous details and 1 to it then insert it

Comment: SELECT COUNT(ft_ticket_number)+100

Comment: @dev0 but what about second value, if i use then second value will be 201 because count(ft_ticket)number) count my last value that is 101 and it will add 101 + 100 so next value 201.

Comment: @Santosh count will give number of records. so increment will work perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just increment the counter by 101.

```
 SELECT COUNT(ft_ticket_number) + 101
```

> **Detailed explanation:**
>
> Initially there are no records for let's say ticket Id 70
>
> `COUNT(ft_ticket_number)` will return `0` for ticket Id 70. So first value will be `0 + 101 = 101`
>
> Next time table already has 1 record. So `COUNT(ft_ticket_number)` will return `1` which will calculate Ticket Number as `1 + 101 = 102` and so on.
>
> The counter will reset automatically for new Ticket Id.

Answer (score 1):

This would be appropriate for you..

```
INSERT INTO jps_final_tickets(ft_ticket_number, ft_event, ft_package_id, ft_contact_person)
                    SELECT COUNT(ft_ticket_number)+101, '$eventID' AS ft_event, '$ticketID' AS ft_package_id, '$contactPerson' AS ft_contact_person,
                    FROM jps_final_tickets WHERE ft_package_id = '$ticketID'
```

Answer (score 0):

What about telling it mysql directly. If you make `ticket_number` an auto increment value starting at 100.

If `jps_ticket_number` is your primary key this will work.

```
ALTER TABLE jps_final_tickets AUTO_INCREMENT=100;
```

Comment: no, i have already primary key, i can make jps_final_tickets as primary.